# Do the Ultramarines have Primaris Squads in their 1st Company?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I’m currently painting an army of Primaris Ultramarines and I’d like them to vaguely canonically accurate.

I know the 1st company is made up veterans, usually terminators. Does the 1st company also contain Primaris squads or have they not been around long enough to earn veteran status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it is possible. Reading some of the details around [1st Company marines](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Veteran_Marines), while most have hundreds of years of experience, a singular act of insane heroism is also qualifies a marine. If their battle brothers believe that they have what it takes, that is all that is required. Just usually those centuries of service are what counts as appropriate evidence.

Which brings us to the Primaris Marines - they are good. Very good. Loyalist Primarch gene seeds and Custodes creation methods are combined to make them bigger and better, and this is reflected in the tabletop stats. Being a project of Roboute Guilliman should make the Ultramarines the most open to accepting the Primaris Marines, so even the excuse of tradition is flimsy. In short, I don't think it would take long for a Primaris Marine to go above and beyond and prove themselves worthy of 1st Company.

Additionally: [The Rubicon Primaris](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Primaris_Space_Marines#The_Rubicon_Primaris) is a process which turns a regular Space Marine into a Primaris Marine. It is painful, lengthy, with a high failure rate (the first subject in fact died on the table and was revived), but it worked. Marneus Calgar rose a Primaris. I'd say it is natural that the strongest, toughest and most valiant Marines of 1st Company would be prime stock for upgrading. So those Primaris Marines in 1st Company might actually be true veterans as well!

Comment: Really good point about the Rubicon Project!!!

Comment: Guilliman has done a lot to encourage the baseline Astartes to accept their new brothers. He has pushed the incorporation of the Primaris within all his successor chapters and even the leadership of Ultramar. We know exactly how many have been woven into the Ultramarines second company (24), to include one becoming a Lieutenant. Guilliman has also granted at least on of the new Primaris a role of Tetrarch leading one of the sub-sectors of Ultramar. Given this I think it is safe to say you can include them, just not too many! I would argue less than ten and you should be within canon...